# yii2 custom field type

Tags: forms, yii2, extending-classes, custom-field-type

I am using Yii2 and I want to create custom active form field type.

For example creatig a text input form field is happending like this:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin();
$form->field($model, 'attribute_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true])
```

I want to make custom json input field type with special rendering and all and use it like this:

```
$form->field($model, 'attribute_name')->JsonInput(['maxlength' => true]);
```

and not like this:

```
$form->field($model, 'attribute_name')->widget('trntv\aceeditor\Widget','mode'=>'json);
```

How can I extend the `yii\widgets\ActiveForm` so that I can add my custom form field types? Is it possible at all?

The only relatable info about this I found is in the [Yii forum](https://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/67511-custom-field-type/), but there the usage format is different:

```
$form->myCheckbox($model, 'attribute_name');
```

and I want the usage to be like the yii form types:

```
$form->field($model, 'attribute_name')->JsonInput(['maxlength' => true]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create:

1. Custom `ActiveField` class with method `JsonInput()` (which calls `widget()` with your widget configuration).
2. Custom `ActiveForm` class with changed [`fieldClass`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#$fieldClass-detail) property to your custom `ActiveField` class. You may add `@method \my\custom\ActiveField field(\yii\base\Model $model, string $attribute, array $options = [])` to PHPDoc of your `ActiveForm` to get better code completion.

You may also skip creating own `ActiveForm` and change `fieldClass` ad hoc:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'fieldClass' => \my\custom\ActiveField::class,
])
```

but you will need to repeat it every time and you will not get code completion for your custom methods in `ActiveField`.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

It worked like a charm. 

The only thing is that the new custom field types are not autocomoleted or recognized from where they come. I included `@method \my\custom\ActiveField field(\yii\base\Model $model, string $attribute, array $options = [])` in my custom `ActiveForm` class.